# Angular 8 project with bootstrap 4 + Angular Material 8 grid

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I have created at angular 8 project with the angular CLI. I have added "@angular/material": "^8.2.3" and "bootstrap": "4.3.1". I have made the following import to the style.scss

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/badge";

html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
```

I have adde a simple example in app-component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <p>dfdf</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <p>dfdf</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <p>dfdf</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <p>dfdf</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>dfdf</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>dfdf</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would expect the same output from the two rows but the first row breaks, which i didn't expect and the second row evenly distribute the the columns in the container. Have i totally misunderstood the concept of col-x?
[Col break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FPlM.png) (Screendump from Chrome OSX)

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is just a rookie mistake.

Comment: What you have there should behave exactly as you describe expecting 3 columns should be evenly distributed at 33.333% so the display you show in your screenshot would make me wonder if perhaps you don't have something else in there being inherited in the styles causing otherwise. Which is tough to troubleshoot if we can't see a way to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a missing import of `@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";` in style.scss. It will introduce som other conflicting styles between bootstrap and material. The problem is shown [here](https://www.amadousall.com/the-good-parts-of-bootstrap-4-you-are-missing-in-your-angular-material-projects/) and a workaround solution is given.